# data files for catkin gtest

Tags: ros, catkin, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a Unit-Test program for my catkin package, using gtest.  I have set up my CMakeLists.txt to compile the unit-test program and link against my package library.  In one of the tests, I would like to read in an external data file to use in the test routine.  This data file is in the same directory as my utest.cpp file: `<package>/test/test.dat`.

In **rosbuild**, I run tests using `make test`, and the working directory is the package root.  So, I can reference the test data file using a relative path: `test/test.dat`.

In **catkin**, I run `make run_tests` and the working directory is in the `catkin_ws/devel` tree.  The build process does not copy my data file to this tree, so it is unclear how I should specify the relative path to my data file.

What is the best-practice for dealing with test data files under catkin?
*NOTE: I don't want the test executable or data-file to be installed in the final package.  These are for unit-test purposes only.*

In case it's helpful, here's the relevant section of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
catkin_add_gtest(test_myPackage test/utest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_myPackage myPackage_lib)
```

---

**EDIT :**
*NOTE: William has updated his example code, so the following bugs have been fixed.  I'm leaving in this discussion for historical reasons, but the updated code should work as-is*

I tried running the example code provided by @William below.  When I rename `test.dat` to `test1.dat`, both tests still pass.  I think the issue is with how the test code loops over the data file lines.  No tests are run if the file is not found, but neither is an error thrown.  Adding the following line helps to catch this case:

```
in.open("data/test.dat", std::fstream::in);
ASSERT_FALSE(in.fail());    // this is the new line
int op1, op2, expected;
while (in >> op1 >> op2 >> expected) {
  EXPECT_EQ(expected, test_with_data::add(op1, op2));
}
```

Once that line is added, both tests fail with the mis-named `test1.dat` file.  However, once the file is restored to the correct name, the second method *still* fails.  If I add a print of the current working directory to `test_with_data2.cpp`, it reports: `ws/build/test_with_data/test`.  It looks like the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` argument is relative to the *build* directory.  However, if you use an *absolute* path, the 2nd test method works as expected:

```
catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}2-test test/test_with_data2.cpp WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59779/data-files-for-catkin-gtest/) by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be solved using `CMake` or using `catkin`.

**CMake Option:**

The CMake way to solve this would be to create a template file which would have the location of the test data injected at build time.

Lets say you had a layout like this:

```
my_pkg/
--include/
--src/
--test/
----data/
------test.dat
----test_with_data.cpp
----test_with_data_settings.h.in
```

The data file might look like this:

```
1 2 3
3 4 7
100 -16 84
```

The test might look like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "test_with_data/add.h"

#include "test_with_data_settings.h"

namespace {

class SomeTests : public ::testing::Test {};

TEST_F(SomeTests, test_add) {
  std::fstream in;
  in.open((std::string(TEST_DIR) + std::string("/test.dat")).c_str(), std::fstream::in);
  ASSERT_FALSE(in.fail());
  int op1, op2, expected;
  while (in >> op1 >> op2 >> expected) {
    EXPECT_EQ(expected, test_with_data::add(op1, op2));
  }
  in.close();
}

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  try {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << "Unhandled Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

The header file might look like:

```
#define TEST_DIR "@TEST_WITH_DATA_TEST_DIR@"
```

And the relavent CMake code:

```
get_filename_component(TEST_WITH_DATA_TEST_DIR "test/data" ABSOLUTE)
configure_file(test/test_with_data_settings.h.in test/test_with_data_settings.h)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test)
catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_with_data.cpp)
if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test add)
endif()
```

**catkin Option:**

The catkin way to solve this would be to use the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option of `catkin_add_gtest` inorder to have your tests run in a place relative to the data location.

So you would drop the settings header and your test would look like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "test_with_data/add.h"

namespace {

class SomeTests : public ::testing::Test {};

TEST_F(SomeTests, test_add) {
  std::fstream in;
  in.open("data/test.dat", std::fstream::in);
  ASSERT_FALSE(in.fail());
  int op1, op2, expected;
  while (in >> op1 >> op2 >> expected) {
    EXPECT_EQ(expected, test_with_data::add(op1, op2));
  }
  in.close();
}

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  try {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << "Unhandled Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

With this CMake code:

```
catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}2-test test/test_with_data2.cpp WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test)
if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}2-test)
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}2-test add)
endif()
```

I have setup a demo package that demonstrates both methods here:

https://github.com/wjwwood/catkin_demos/tree/master/test_with_data

You can run them by making a workspace, and invoking `catkin_make run_tests`:

```
$ mkdir test_ws
$ cd test_ws
$ mkdir src
$ cd src
$ ln -s /path/to/catkin_demos/test_with_data ./
$ source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash  # OR ln -s /path/to/catkin ./
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make run_tests              # OR ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make run_tests
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-04-02**:
Thanks for the very thorough answer.  I was able to download & run your test code successfully.  My first try at porting Option #2 to my code resulted in an error: "No such file or directory: 'test'", but I'll look more into it tomorrow.  I should be able to figure it out from your example.

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-04-02**:
I got a chance to test out this demo code more tonight, and think I found some "bugs".  See my edits to the original question above.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-02**:
@Jeremy Zoss Thanks for catching those bugs! I'll update the example and the answer.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-03**:
Nice work, guys! We need a catkin doc page describing how to build unit tests. This would make a valuable start.